# Gradle with TestNg: No tests found

Tags: java, gradle, testng

I am using gradle project

1. Project is working fine with junit, but
2. with TestNg i am getting build fail error with this

```
    Testing started at 9:18 PM ...
    9:18:08 PM: Executing tasks ':cleanTest :test --tests "abc.lau" --scan'...

    > Task :cleanTest
    > Task :compileJava NO-SOURCE
    > Task :processResources NO-SOURCE
    > Task :classes UP-TO-DATE
    > Task :compileTestJava
    > Task :processTestResources NO-SOURCE
    > Task :testClasses
    > Task :test FAILED
    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
    * What went wrong:
    Execution failed for task ':test'.
    > No tests found for given includes: [abc.lau](filter.includeTestsMatching)
    * Try:
    Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
    * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
    BUILD FAILED in 0s
    3 actionable tasks: 3 executed
```

Comment: Can you please explain how yu start the tests (tell the exact command or procedure for both junit and testng)? Since you use filter 'abc.lau', can you explain whether this filtering is correct?

Answer (score 7):

did you explicitly  specify in **build.gradle** that you use testng?

```
test {
    useTestNG()
}
```

Comment: If you are using Kotlin DSL, in build.gradle.kts, use `tasks.test { useTestNG() }`.